# Difference between autonomic and paratonic movements in plants

Tags: botany

I can't understand the difference be because both involvery the main cause that is an external stimuli, so how do they differ(

Answer (score -1):

its about the gene that is involved in autonomic movements. while, there is no gene involved in plants for paratonic movements.furthermore, autonomic movements are presents in plants by birth, and paratonic movements are induced in plants by an external stimuli only and not present in plants by birth.

Comment: There is no need to post a second answer to supplement a previous answer you gave. Instead, you can use the [edit button of your previous answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/74602/edit).

Answer (score -1):

In other words for autonomic movements the plants use an internal cause( simply indicating to gene) and external stimuli both. while, paratonic movemens use external cause only( light, temperature,gravity etc.Hope you understand